# Bⁿ and coherence

Tags: homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, coherence

I understand that an internal abelian group in CW-complexes (while it is not the most extensive structure for which this can be done) produces a classifying space which itself has the structure of an internal abelian group in the derived category:

$$BA \times BA \rightarrow BA$$

It would be nice to hear about some kind of product preservation property of the classifying space functor

$$B : CW \rightarrow Ho(CW)$$

This produces in fact an internal abelian group, and it is the way I prefer to form Eilenberg-Maclane spaces. **The main feature I am examining is a B-functor which can be iterated like so**:

$$B^{n} := B \circ \cdots \circ B$$

This specifically entails abelian groups of some kind, at least in the homotopy category.

There are many subtleties here that I wanted some help with:

1. (Coherence concerning the target of B) it is said that not all H-spaces are E-infinity spaces. I am more interested in a B construction which can be iterated than having the most natural notion of coherence, but with that said, what is the most natural structure to say that BA has for an internal abelian group in CW?
2. (Coherence concerning the domain of B) B can be constructed for an internal group in  CW, but also for a more extensive kind of object. What is the most natural higher structure that the domain of B would have?

With this said, in the context of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces, I am far more interested in a functorial B which can be iterated, as is suggested by $B^{n}$, than in using the most extensive or natural higher or operadic notion of coherence (though I guess I could get both). My last question is what the most typical domain and codomain are for B in a context in which B can be iterated, i.e. we can for the composite

My question is what the most natural definition of B is which can specifically be iterated, if not abelian groups in the homotopy category. I have an impression that people prefer operadic structures and coherence of various kinds, but I have also heard that it is the case that there are H-spaces (internal commutative monoids in the homotopy category) which do not arise from E-infinity spaces.

Comment: The notions of coherence you mention were invented to answer this question.   For any $E_\infty$ space $A$,  the classifying space $BA$ is also an $E_\infty$ space.  There are various notions which are equivalent to $E_\infty$ spaces (e.g. Segal's $\Gamma$ spaces or $\infty$-categorical versions)-- but they all express the "full, most general, coherence data", because you need all of it to deloop.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I don't understand why an E${}_{\infty}$ space has homotopy inverses.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I think I wanted something like that ΩX ∧ ΩY ⭢ Ω(X ∧Y) is a weak equivalence when Ω(X ∧Y) is abelian up to homotopy. A picture for it is like the game twister with the colored spots; S² is what you get when you glue the perimeter of the twister game to a point, and the spots can be moved around with the extra space being sent to a point.

Comment: @PhilTosteson also, I am under the impression that B works on any internal abelian group in the homotopy category of CW complexes. I'm trying to figure out which of these arise from E${}_{\infty}$ spaces.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I'm not sure exactly which internal abelian groups in Ho(CW) arise from E${}_{∞}$-spaces... maybe you know.

Comment: You're right an $E_\infty$ space doesn't have homotopy inverses-- you don't need them to build the bar construction. However, you cannot perform $B$ on homotopy abelian groups.  I don't know a recipe for which homotopy abelian groups can be lifted to $E_\infty$ spaces-- there should be a relevant obstruction theory, but I don't expect there to be a simple answer.

Comment: @PhilTosteson thanks, I think I begin to understand. This is really helpful. Right now I'm wondering if there is a name for when an E∞-space has homotopy coherent inverses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One natural setting where the delooping operation $\def\B{{\sf B}}\B$ can be defined very quickly is Γ-spaces, described by Segal in [Categories and cohomology theories](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(74)90022-6).
A Γ-space is simply a functor $\def\FinSet{{\sf FinSet}}\def\Spc{{\sf Spc}}\FinSet_*→\Spc$.  The delooping operation simply sends a Γ-space $A$ to the Γ-space $\B A$, where $\B A(S)$ is the realization of the simplicial space $T↦A(S⨯T)$.  Additional references on Γ-spaces can be found in the nLab article [Γ-space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gamma-space).

The model category of Γ-spaces is Quillen equivalent to the other models of homotopy coherent commutative monoids and/or infinite loop spaces, e.g., $\def\Ei{{\sf E}_{\sf\infty}}\Ei$-spaces (group-like or not), defined using some choice of an $\Ei$-operad.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping I could get some more info from you before I accept. So, I think I can show that B commutes with products for internal abelian groups in Ho(CW) up to weak equivalence. Does this sound right? Meanwhile I'm not sure exactly which internal abelian groups in Ho(CW) arise from E${}_{∞}$-spaces. It would be really great if you could help me figure out which do.

Comment: @RonaldJ.Zallman: In order to define the delooping functor B, it is not sufficient to have an abelian group object in Ho(CW).  Way too much information is lost when passing to the homotopy category, and in general, in the modern literature you no longer see (for the most part) people working with algebraic constructions in Ho(CW) in the first place.  To define B, you need a (homotopy coherent) abelian group object (more generally, an abelian monoid object) in the actual category of spaces, not in the homotopy category.

Comment: @RonaldJ.Zallman: The functor B commutes with homotopy products.  Lifting abelian group objects in Ho(CW) to E_∞-spaces is a nontrivial problem, the space of liftings is in general noncontractible.  I am not aware of any general theorems, perhaps more could be said for a specific problem.